# Does changing bind-address in mysql to public server Ip lower performance?

Tags: mysql, performance

According to this document
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-remote-database-to-optimize-site-performance-with-mysql

To connect from external ip to mysql I have to change to public ip of the server
bind-address        = your_database_IP

I put here my public IP server.

So my question is does it lose performance. Does it understand that this ip actually its on ip so it will act like local database? Or it will think it is external ip so goes in internet and comes back again ?

Comment: It doesn't lose performance. There's no round-trip in MySQL, it's not querying itself over TCP/IP protocol. You connect to MySQL daemon and send SQL queries to it. To connect to the daemon, you enter this IP address, which is loopback or public IP. Once connected, you're done. What confuses you exactly with the last part of your question?

Comment: resolving of the IP.
If it is 127.0.0.1 it already knows that it is itself. But for public IP I was not sure if it understands automaticly and has same effect as 127.0.0.1
because if I write public IP of the server remotely I can connect this mysql so if it is allowing this kind of connection I wonder if it is lowering performance.

Comment: But why would it have to understand that it is "itself"? It doesn't care. MySQL binds to a network interface. Network interface takes care of this stuff, MySQL simply *receives* data from it. MySQL isn't a chat program or something similar that has to know that public IP is pointing to the same machine.

Comment: Int the link I wrote in my message there is this sentence
"If you are hosting this in a datacenter with private networking capabilities, use your server's private network IP. Otherwise, you can use the public IP address here:"

Then I am confused if it has better performance or not?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/438156/binding-mysql-to-run-from-the-public-or-private-lan-ip-address-which-one-is-fa
I found this maybe thats the answer.

Comment: I can't see what the issue is. If you have a site that is on the same machine as your database, use the local IP. It's faster. If you have the need to connect to MySQL from outside, use public IP. You can use both of course. That means for local purposes, you can connect to local IP.

Answer (score 0):

Connection possibilities:

1. Socket -- the fastest, but only works when client and server are on the same hardware (or, in some cases, the same VM)
2. TCP/IP on the same hardware, but through the TCP/IP stack, so slightly slower for queries.
3. Domain name lookup, and other issues dealing with establishing remote (not same machine) connection.  This action is done only during connecting.  So, it might slow down establishing the connection, but not the queries.  Note: the translation from "foo.com" to "1.2.3.4", if needed, is done once, only during the establishment of the connection.  An explicit IP address is faster, but less flexible.
4. Proxy server / load balancer / etc -- these sit between the client and the server, and add some delay (and some benefit) during all queries.
5. Connection pooling in the client -- some overhead or savings on connecting.
6. Connection pooling in the server -- some overhead or savings on connecting.  (Whether to reuse a process (thread) versus create a new one.)

The beauty of TCP/IP is that you can send a message to any IP address you know; the 'network' will figure out how to get there (anywhere in the world).  It may take one route now, another route the next time.  So it is "reliable", but inconsistent is speed.  It also has a good level of "guaranteed delivery".  Once connected, that is what queries do -- send to a known IP address and get replies.

(See the other comments for more info.)